# Proof verification: a set of $10$ times but not $11$ times differentiable functions is not a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I need to find a counterexample showing that the set of $10$ times but not $11$ times partially differentiable functions is not a vector space (under the usual $+$ operator for functions and usual multiplications with a scalar).

**My attempt**

$f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto -|x|+1$. $f$ is not (partially) differentiable at $0$.

$\int_{-1}^x f(t) dt = \frac{1}{2}(x+1)f(x)$

$\int_{-1}^x \int_{-1}^x f(t) dt = \frac{1}{6}(x+1)^2f(x)$

$\int_{-1}^x ...\int_{-1}^x f(t) dt = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}(x+1)^nf(x)$

So $\frac{1}{11!}(x+1)^{10}f(x)$ is $10$ times (partially) differentiable, its $10$th derivative is $f(x)$, thus it is not $11$ times (partially) differentiable.

$g:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto -f(x)$, $\frac{1}{11!}(x+1)^{10}g(x)$ is also $10$ times but not $11$ times (partially) differentiable.

$\frac{1}{11!}(x+1)^{10}g(x) + \frac{1}{11!}(x+1)^{10}f(x)=0$ is (partially) differentiable as many times as needed.

Comment: **Much quicker hint:** Is there a zero vector at all?

Comment: **Picky remark**: You should specify what the operations are (sum, product with a scalar). There might be weird operations you have not thought of and that make your set a vector space. (Indeed there are: you know from set theory that a bijection from your set onto $\mathbb{R}$ exists, so you may equip your set with the inherited operations. Technically speaking, this is a vector space).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ok, I have specified it.